# Sending email confirmation delayed after Register in ASP.NET MVC & Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm having a problem with the confirmation email or reset password on my ASP.NET MVC project.

When I register to my app which is hosted in Azure (also the DB is in Azure), the confirmation email is not coming in time. 
I have delays for like 5 minutes, sometimes 1 hour or sometimes it doesn't come at all. The same thing happens for Reset password email.

When I try it locally on my project they usually comes in time.

Here is my code:

```
public class Smtp
    {
        iBridgeEntities db;
        OperatorSetting settings;
        public Smtp() {
            db = new iEntities();
            settings = new OperatorSetting();
            settings = db.OperatorSettings.Where(s => s.Name == "Smtp").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public bool SendEmail(Email email)
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(email.From);
                mail.To.Add(email.To);
                mail.Subject = email.Subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = email.IsBodyHtml;          
                mail.Body = email.Body;
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(settings.Username, settings.Password);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```